# Sending compressed text over Amazon SQS from PHP to NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, zlib, amazon-sqs

I seem to be stuck at sending the compressed messages from PHP to NodeJS over Amazon SQS.

Over on the PHP side I have:

```
$SQS->sendMessage(Array(
    'QueueUrl'    => $queueUrl,
    'MessageBody' => 'article',
    'MessageAttributes' => Array(
        'json' => Array(
            'BinaryValue' => bzcompress(json_encode(Array('type'=>'article','data'=>$vijest))),
            'DataType' => 'Binary'
        )
    )
));
```

NOTE 1: I also tried putting compressed data directly in the message, but the library gave me an error with some invalid byte data

On the Node side, I have:

```
body = decodeBzip(message.MessageAttributes.json.BinaryValue);
```

Where message is from sqs.receiveMessage() call and that part works since it worked for raw (uncompressed messages)

What I am getting is **TypeError: improper format**

I also tried using:

> PHP - NODE
>
> gzcompress() - zlib.inflateraw()
>
> gzdeflate() - zlib.inflate()
>
> gzencode() - zlib.gunzip()

And each of those pairs gave me their version of the same error (essentially, input data is wrong)

Given all that I started to suspect that an error is somewhere in message transmission

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**: It seems that the error is somewhere in transmission, since bin2hex() in php and .toString('hex') in Node return totally different values. It seems that Amazon SQS API in PHP transfers BinaryAttribute using base64 but Node fails to decode it. I managed to partially decode it by turning off automatic conversion in amazon aws config file and then manually decoding base64 in node but it still was not able to decode it.

**EDIT 2**: I managed to accomplish the same thing by using base64_encode() on the php side, and sending the base64 as a messageBody (not using MessageAttributes). On the node side I used new Buffer(messageBody,'base64') and then decodeBzip on that. It all works but I would still like to know why MessageAttribute is not working as it should. Current base64 adds overhead and I like to use the services as they are intended, not by work arounds.

Comment: SQS is fundamentally intended for text-oriented messages -- [*"Amazon SQS messages can contain up to 256KB of text data"*](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/) -- Unless the JSON encoding process somehow always coincidentally produces valid UTF-8 output, I can see why there would be a problem...   base64-encoding the payload will, of course, undo some of the benefit of the compression, since encoding base-64 causes a 3:4 byte expansion... but should still result in a net decrease in payload size.   Give that a try?

Comment: Yes but SQS does have BinaryAttribute which is supposed to be used exactly for that? They even say in their documentation that BinaryAttribute can be used for transferring images, compressed data, etc.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are doing, there.  Fair question.  I'll look further.

Comment: I would examine the raw message received from SQS, comparing the bytes found in message.MessageAttributes.json.BinaryValue to the bytes you originally wrote into there.  Whether it's getting corrupted or altered should be easy to establish if you examine a hex dump on both sides.

Comment: I am doing that as we speak, but even if I find the difference, that still does not tell me why. I am also trying to encode the same string on both sides to see if that is implementation error.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't tell you why, but it helps sectionalize the trouble by eliminating what the problem is not -- if it's not being altered, then it's not the transport, so the "why" must something in your code -- but if it is being altered, you can then take further steps to figure out why.

Comment: Testing that, bin2hex() in PHP and .toString('hex') in Node give completely different output. I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: Also, NodeJS buffer always seems to start with <Buffer 05 98 78 d4 06 3f 49 8f ff...> I wonder what is that all about

Comment: I would expect the output from `bzcompress()` to begin with `42 5a 68`, the first three bytes of the bzip2 magic number.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that SQS library internally uses base64 to transfer BinaryAttribute, so when I disabled automatic conversion and did base64 manually I did get 42 5a 68 .... but there were a lot of FFs and it still was not able to decompress it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequests_MakingQueryRequestsArticle.html#POSTRequests) is what all the SQS libraries do under the hood. You can get the php source code of the SQS library and see for yourself. Binary data will **always** be base64 encoded (when using *MessageAttributes* or not, does not matter) as a way to satisfy the API requirement of having form-url-encoded messages.

I do not know how long the data in your $vijest is, but I am willing to bet that after zipping and then base64 encoding it will be bigger than before.

So my answer to you would be two parts (plus a third if you are really stubborn):

- When looking at the underlying raw API it is absolutely clear that not using MessageAttributes does NOT add additional overhead from base64. Instead, using MessageAttributes adds some slight additional overhead because of the structure of the data enforced by the SQS php library. So not using MessageAttributes is clearly NOT a workaround and you should do it if you want to zip the data yourself and you got it to work that way.
- Because of the nature of a http POST request it is a very bad idea to compress your data inside your application. Base64 overhead will likely nullify the compression advantage and you are probably better off sending plain text.
- If you absolutely do not believe me or the API spec or the HTTP spec and want to proceed, then I would advise to send a simple short string 'teststring' in the BinaryValue parameter and compare what you sent with what you got. That will make it very easy to understand the transformations the SQS library is doing on the BinaryValue parameter.

Comment: Thank you! You confirmed what I realized just earlier today. I am not sure why did I think that using it like this adds overhead, when in the end it's all url, so shorter the message object, shorter the url. My messages are about 10k average, and gzip reduces that to about 3k. So, with it's 4:3 ratio it's about 4. Multiply that with about 2.000 messages per hour, it does make a difference.

Thank you for the insight!

Comment: One thing still bothers me tho. If PHP side does base64 encode, and Node does decode, why does it fail on the Node side? Shouldn't it be transparent?

Comment: But you should check if curl or whatever php uses to send the messages and the Amazon Webserver do not zip the messages anyways. I did not look very thorough but I found at least some evidence that the communication is zipped anyways. Fire up wireshark and look for content-encoding:gzip in the messages.

Comment: And to your other question, you could use my 3rd part to analyze that. My guess would be that they dont really test their node server with the php client and something went wrong. Can you test your php client against a php server? Also, may I politely ask for the bounty? :)

Comment: As much as your answer did not clarify "why" is it happening, it helped me realize that there is in fact no overhead when using base64 as message text (au contraire, it might even use less data to transfer), so yes, you can have the bounty :)

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`gzcompress()` would be decoded by `zlib.Inflate()`. `gzdeflate()` would be decoded by `zlib.InflateRaw()`. `gzencode()` would be decoded by `zlib.Gunzip()`. So out of the three you listed, two are wrong, but one should work.

Comment: Hey Mark, I thought of that so I tried all possible combinations (even using some 3rd party modules for Node) but it still failed. If you check my question (Edit 1), error seems to be somewhere in transmission because in Node I receive something totally different from what I sent in PHP.