# Enable compression for AWS SQS Java API or how to tell if it's already on?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm doing some processing of AWS SQS messages and noticed that the process is network-bound.

The messages are highly-compressible large JSON content, and they were dropped into the queue without any compression on the payload itself.

Does the AWS SQS API perform compression on the wire? If optional, how can I enable it?

A Google search for *AWS SQS API compression* yields a bunch of information on AWS API Gateway, which is totally unrelated to my question.

Comment: Why do you want to compress JSON data? If it is a part of requirement you may use some third party libraries for compressing the json data after reading it from queue.

Comment: it's for performance, so compressing after reading would not be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this will provide some clarity? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844377/sending-compressed-text-over-amazon-sqs-from-php-to-nodejs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQS does not support automatic/transparent compression.

To compress messages, you'd have to compress the payload yourself (e.g. with gzip) and then you'd have to encode the compressed data with base64, because SQS supports only *character* data -- valid utf8 -- not raw binary data.

(Additionally it seems unlikely that you are network-bound when polling.  You may need to investigate this in more detail.)

Comment: how about compression on the wire... during the HTTP requests that the SQS API makes under the covers. Can't that compress the transmission even if the payload on the message is not compressed?

Comment: Theoretically, that could work, if, for example, SQS observed the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` request header and encoded the responses with Gzip... but I have never observed it, and don't believe it to be supported.

Comment: If anyone is still interested, I just built an extension on top of the Extended sqs client that does exactly that. I'll clean it up over the weekend and package it. I built it for .net but it should be easy enough to port to Java or whatever is your favourite flavour.

Comment: Okay, couldn't help myself and just fixed it up real quick. Here you go: https://github.com/dimi3tron/Amazon.SQS.ExtendClient.Compression or just: Install-Package AWSSQS.ExtendClient.Compression -Version 1.0.0-beta1

There are no options for now (size treshhold, compresion level, or whatever) but I'll probably add those soon.
It'd be cool if someone would port this thing to Java. I'd be glad to help out, even though I haven't written any Java since 1.4 :P

Answer (score 2):

If ur messages are more than 256 KB,either split it and if u cannot split it put it on S3 and send the s3 link as a message in queue.
GZIP and then Base64 ends up increasing message size...It is not worth the effort to try that..
I spent close to an hour trying this with various text and json messages..I was not getting any considerable saving in message size after gzipping and base64 encoding..

On Small text size messages, my zipped and base64 message was around 30 percent higher in size than simple text message